Media3 MediaSessionService in recyclerView
help me figure out how to properly implement the playback function using the media3 ExoPlayer library in RecyclerView.
Multiple audio recordings may be displayed on the screen.
My current implementation :
My media service
@UnstableApi
class PlayerService : MediaSessionService(),MediaSession.Callback {
    companion object {
        private val _isPlay = MutableStateFlow<Boolean>(false)
        val isPlay: StateFlow<Boolean> = _isPlay

        var currentVoiceName: String? = null
    }

    private var mediaSession: MediaSession? = null

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        val exoPlayer =
            ExoPlayer.Builder(applicationContext, DefaultRenderersFactory(applicationContext))
                .setLoadControl(
                    DefaultLoadControl.Builder()
                        .setPrioritizeTimeOverSizeThresholds(false).build()
                )
                .setTrackSelector(
                    DefaultTrackSelector(
                        applicationContext,
                        AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory()
                    )
                )
                .setMediaSourceFactory(
                    ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(
                        CacheDataSource.Factory()
                            .setCache(AppCommunity.cache)
                            .setUpstreamDataSourceFactory(
                                DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory()
                                    .setUserAgent("Exoplayer")
                            )
                            .setFlags(CacheDataSource.FLAG_IGNORE_CACHE_ON_ERROR)
                    )
                )
                .build()
        mediaSession = MediaSession.Builder(this, exoPlayer).setCallback(this).build()
        exoPlayer.addListener(object : Player.Listener {
            override fun onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState: Int) {
                _isPlay.value = !(playbackState == Player.STATE_ENDED && !exoPlayer.isPlaying)
                Timber.d("IsPlay = ${_isPlay.value}")
                if (!_isPlay.value) {
                    currentVoiceName = null
                    mediaSession?.player?.clearMediaItems()
                }
                super.onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState)
            }

            override fun onMediaItemTransition(mediaItem: MediaItem?, reason: Int) {
                currentVoiceName = mediaItem?.mediaMetadata?.artist?.toString()
                super.onMediaItemTransition(mediaItem, reason)
            }
        })
    }

    override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {
        val player = mediaSession?.player!!
        if (!player.playWhenReady
            || player.mediaItemCount == 0
            || player.playbackState == Player.STATE_ENDED
        ) stopSelf()

    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        mediaSession?.run {
            player.release()
            release()
            mediaSession = null
        }
    }

    override fun onGetSession(controllerInfo: MediaSession.ControllerInfo): MediaSession? {
        return mediaSession
    }

    override fun onConnect(
        session: MediaSession,
        controller: MediaSession.ControllerInfo
    ): MediaSession.ConnectionResult {
        Timber.d(controller.toString())
        return super.onConnect(session, controller)
    }


View holder audio in recyclerView:
override fun onBinding(item: MessageItem) {
        super.onBinding(item)
        if (item !is MessageItem.ContentMessage)
            return

        binding.time.text = item.createDateAt
        if (item.editDateAt != null) {
            binding.time.text = itemView.context.getString(R.string.change_in, item.editDateAt)
        }

        if (item.itemMessageState == MessageState.DISPLAYED)
            binding.checkMarkers.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_check_marks_done)
        else binding.checkMarkers.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_check_send)
        val mediaItem = MediaItem.Builder()
            .setUri(item.listContent[0].uri)
            .setMediaId(item.itemMessageId)
            .setMediaMetadata(
                MediaMetadata.Builder()
                    .setArtist(item.userName)
                    .setTitle(itemView.context.getString(R.string.voice))
                    .build()
            )

        val sessionToken = SessionToken(itemView.context, ComponentName(itemView.context, PlayerService::class.java))
        controllerFuture = MediaController.Builder(itemView.context, sessionToken).buildAsync()
        controllerFuture!!.addListener(
            {
                with(controllerFuture!!.get()) {
                    addMediaItem(mediaItem.build())
                    binding.exoplayerView.player = this
                    playWhenReady = false
                    prepare()
                }

            },
            MoreExecutors.directExecutor()
        )
    }

    private fun releasePlayer() {
        binding.exoplayerView.player?.release()
        binding.exoplayerView.player = null
        controllerFuture?.let { MediaController.releaseFuture(it) }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        Timber.d("onDestroyView")
        releasePlayer()
    }


If you click on the play button, one audio recording is played in both playercontrolviews.
image my voices in recyclerView
How to properly manage audio recordings in this case?
